# What’s the correct way to “hook up” the magnifying glass icon in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableViewController that contains a UISearchBarController for searching. I have all of the searching functionality in place, and it works fine, but I’d like to follow the usual convention of the search bar being accessible from a magnifying-glass icon in the section index. I know I can get the icon by including `UITableViewIndexSearch` in the array returned by `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`, but how do I scroll to the search bar when the user taps on the magnifying glass? I guess I need to add something to `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`, but I don’t know what since (as far as I know) the search controller isn’t really in any of the table’s sections.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like below within `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` to display the search bar. First statement animates the search bar, second one scrolls up to the very first section.

```
if ([title isEqualToString:UITableViewIndexSearch]) 
{
    [self.searchController setActive:TRUE animated:TRUE];
    return 0;
}
```